# Linux application over RDP (FreeRDP, XRDP) / Apache Guacamole

Tags: linux, remoteapp, guacamole

I have started lately using Apache Guacamole.
The problem I am facing is that I want to find a way to have Linux Remote Applications over RDP ( as windows RemoteApp does).

Is there any way to have just a single Linux application using xrdp or freerdp?

I have tried the initial_program option but this brings the whole desktop with the application running.

If none of them works is there any other way?

As far as I understand, in Guacamole, only via RDP there might be a chance to bring a single Linux app. Neither VNC nor SSH can be used for that purpose.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: what do you mean by Linux Remote Applications? means do you want to access the remote machine from the linux?

Comment: Actually I want to access only one application (not the whole desktop) of the remote machine via web browser. This is why I use Guacamole. This can be implemented in case of Windows OS via RemoteApps, and I need to know if there is way to have the same result in case of Linux applications.